# Pass variable to template callback

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Recently I started getting familiar with meteor platform, and I stumbled on dilemma:
Is there a way to pass variables to Template.rendered, Template.created callbacks.
Let's say I have route

```
Router.route('/profile/:_id', {
    name: 'profile'
});
```

and I want to somehow to pass that _id variable to Template.rendered callback:

```
Template.profile.rendered = function () {
    //how can I get "_id" in here?
};
```

Is this possible? If so how can I do it?

Comment: Save this.params._id as a Session variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you declare a route, you also specify a data context to provide to the template that will be rendered :

```
Router.route('/profile/:_id', {
  name: 'profile',
  data: function(){
    return Meteor.users.findOne(this.params._id);
  }
});
```

This way you can reference the user _id coming from the current data context assigned to the profile template like this :

```
Template.profile.rendered = function () {
  console.log(this.data._id);
};
```